# How to queue, pause and resume download Alamofire.Request?

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm using Alamofire as my HTTP framework, I'm currently using NSOperation and NSOperationQueue to limit my concurrent request to 3. This works fine without modifying my request queue. However, I'm in a situation when I need to pause a current operation, by doing so, the next operation must start its download request. Can someone guide me to do this scenario?